# Error on installation - Office 365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, 64-bit, office365, 32-bit

I'm using Windows 10 and had Office 365 installed on my pc.
The problem was: I had a `64-Bit` version installed from the `office 365 website` which installed it as `64-Bit`. For legacy reasons I need the `32-Bit` version.
So I deinstalled `Office` in the `Settings > Apps & Features` Panel and headed to `Company Portal` to install the right version.
But it always failes with: `Error on installation` without further information.
Clicking on the link opens: `windows error 0x80070642 site:microsoft.com` on a search engine. I have the option to `repeat`, but it won't work, even after rebooting my computer.
Is there some kind of cache I have to delete or what else can I do to resolve this?

Comment: "For legacy reasons"...?

Comment: Access db which is in 32-Bit and cannot be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because there is residue after uninstalling 64-bit version of Office 365. Please try to completely uninstall Office with the uninstall support tool. You can download the tool from the page [Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8).

If the Office unistall tool doesn't completely uninstall Office from your PC, you can [manually uninstall Click-to-Run installation of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b).

You can also [perform a clean boot in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) and reinstall 32-bit version of Office 365 to have a check.